# Flutter How can I validate only 'https' and reject 'http' using form_field_validator?

Tags: regex, flutter, validation

I am trying to make a validation for URL which is accept only 'https' and reject 'http'. I am using form_field_validator for it and I probably understand how to use it. However, I have no idea how to write the regex. Could anyone help me to solve this? This is the code down below.

**url_validator.dart**

```
import 'package:form_field_validator/form_field_validator.dart';

class UrlValidator extends TextFieldValidator {
  UrlValidator({required String errorText}) : super(errorText);

  // I would like to validate only 'https' but this code doesn't work
  var urlPattern =
      r'https';

  @override
  bool isValid(String? value) => RegExp(urlPattern).hasMatch(value!);
}
```

**validators.dart**

```
import 'package:form_field_validator/form_field_validator.dart';

final urlValidator = MultiValidator([
  UrlValidator(errorText: 'URL is invalid'),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to validate URLs in Flutter using the form_field_validator package. To accept only "https" URLs and reject "http" URLs, you can use the following regular expression pattern and a RegExp validator:

`RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^https://[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$');`

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to use regular expressions to validate URLs and accept only those starting with 'https' while rejecting 'http'. You are on the right track, but the regular expression pattern you provided in url_validator.dart is not correctly defining the rule you want. You can achieve this by using a regular expression like this:

```
import 'package:form_field_validator/form_field_validator.dart';

class UrlValidator extends TextFieldValidator {
   UrlValidator({required String errorText}) : super(errorText);

   // Use a regular expression to validate 'https' URLs
   var urlPattern = r'^https:\/\/';

   @override
   bool isValid(String? value) => RegExp(urlPattern).hasMatch(value!);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex hope this will work.

```dart
final RegExp httpsPattern = RegExp(r'^https://');
```